# boot failure on ubuntu 20.04.2

Tags: boot, nvidia, 20.04, boot-repair

I want to ask ubuntu 20.04.2 I always experience boot fail which causes it to force shutdown, which makes hardware component lifespan shorter ... maybe someone can help me solve this problem

Comment: No errors not info of any kind?

Comment: right at the start of starting the engine after the Asus logo then the screen immediately went black